# Error 0 byte when save image to local or other server

Tags: php

```
function grab_image($url, $saveto){
        $url = $url;
        $ch = curl_init ($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
        $raw = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        if(file_exists($saveto)){
            unlink($saveto);
        }
        $fp = fopen($saveto, 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $raw);
        fclose($fp);
    }
$link = 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/415lKuJC%2B2L.jpg';
grab_image($link, '/tmp/415lKuJC%2B2L.jpg');
```

Error when save to local file (0 byte), I think this link have special character is %2B

Comment: your `$saveto` path is wrong. change this to like `"/tmp/test.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding file name in function call, like following:

```
grab_image($link, "/tmp/new_file_name.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

alternative solution to grab file with original filename:

```
function grab_image($url, $savePath = getcwd())
{
    $path = $savePath.'/'.basename($url);
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        unlink();
    }
    copy($url, $path);
}

$link = 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/415lKuJC%2B2L.jpg';
grab_image($link);
```